# change document root in all links of a website

Tags: html, document-root

I have a website made with cakephp. Most of the links in it, and asset paths, are absolute (start with "/").

We're having some problems with our hosting provider and some domains are messed up, including the one for this website. I've managed to access it through another domain, but now the website instead of being on the document root of the domain (as it was with its original domain), it inside a few folders (so something like mydomain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/my_index.php).

Is there an easy way I can make all those links/paths that now start with "/" point to the folder that I want (for example mydomain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/) instead of what happens now? (they point to mydomain.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want the `<base>` HTML tag. Use it like such:

```
<head>
    <base href="http://mydomain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/">
</head>
```

You can also make all your links open in a new window by adding a `target="_blank"` attribute to the base tag.

MDN Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I can't make it work with links/paths that start by "/", only the one that start without "/". So with `<img src="my/path/image.jpg">` it works, but not with `<img src="/my/path/image.jpg">`. Any ideas why? Or is it just supposed to not work that way?

Comment: Right, because "/my/path" is an absolute path where "/" is domain root. "my/path" is a relative path which will use the interpreted or defined document root and will utilize the `<base>` tag.